# rxjs Observable import issue

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, tslint, rxjs6

I've tried:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

which gives me the error:

> node_modules/rxjs/Obserable has no exported member 'Observable'

and I've tried:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

which gives me the TSLINT error:

> This import is blacklisted

I know I can fix this by removing the 'rxjs' `import-blacklist` entry from tslint.json but I don't want to do that. I'm sure its there for a good reason. How do I correctly do the import? thanks

EDIT: Changed to capital O - see comment

Comment: What version of RxJS are you using? The latest - v6 - has far fewer import locations than v5 and `'rxjs/observable'` no longer exists (and, in any case, it should have had a capital `O`). Instead, you should import from `'rxjs'` and you should remove that import location from the blacklist. The linting rule is not appropriate for v6. See the [migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you are using RxJS version 6.

In version 6, the number of import locations was greatly reduced. In particular, the `'rxjs/Observable'` import no longer exists and the `Observable` class should be imported from `'rxjs'` like this:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

That means the blacklist you were using is no longer appropriate for version 6 and will need to be reconfigured or disabled.

The other changes that were made to the import locations in version 6 are discussed in the [migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md) - which also explains how the `rxjs-compat` package can be used to ease the migration from version 5 to version 6.

Comment: wonderful thanks - worth noting that when using Angular's ng update ... ng update @angular/core ... it auto installs rxjs-compat ... read more here ... https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4#7a6c